Why are some heuristics successful?
Mathematicians sometimes use heuristics to form expectations about what might be true or false. For examples, see Matthew Emerton's answer to Why should I believe the Mordell Conjecture?, this blog post by Terence Tao, and this expository article by Barry Mazur.
Such heuristics occupy a funny position in the epistemology of mathematics. We tend to think that using such heuristics somehow makes "more sense" than, say, reading tea leaves to decide which football team to bet on. We know they can be misleading, yet we allow ourselves to be influenced by them. Indeed, this MO question provides an example of heuristics leading to two contradictory conclusions.
Question: Has it ever happened that a conjecture supported by heuristics was proved, and then an explanation was found for the success of the heuristics? Concretely, this might mean that the heuristic argument was developed into a rigorous proof.
Example: When the umbral calculus was first discovered, it was mysterious that the seemingly nonsensical operation of "turning indices into exponents" could yield correct identities.
Example: The Cramér probabilistic model of the prime numbers predicts that the Riemann hypothesis is true. After the Riemann hypothesis is proved, as no doubt it eventually will, it would remain to be understood why the Cramér model was successful (at least in the case of RH).
Timothy Chow suggests in the comments that heuristics like the Cramér model are, in some sense, precise expressions of the imprecise hypothesis that "nothing weird happens".
Question: Have any attempts been made to formulate a conjecture that reflects the hypotheses underlying the Cramér model? Such a conjecture would be very powerful indeed, since it would imply the Riemann Hypothesis, Legendre's Conjecture, the Twin Prime Conjecture, and more.

I'd say that's what happens most of the times when heuristics lead to correct predictions and then to theorems: the proof grows often up from the heuristics themselves.

Here’s a heuristic for why heuristics work: because they’ve worked in the past.

I think almost every nontrivial proof is preceded by successful heuristics. Such heuristics may sometimes be also called ideas.

Related: Rigorous version of heuristic argument for genus-degree formula?

I think a lot of heuristics are of the form, "Nothing weird happens." The Cramér model says that the sequence of primes doesn't contain any weird structure. Similarly, the only thing stopping many heuristic arguments from being rigorous is that some bizarre counterexample isn't ruled out. So when the rigorous proof arrives, and the ghosts are banished, I'm not sure that it "explains" the heuristic beyond confirming that what we thought would be too bizarre to be true is indeed too bizarre to be true. That is, the explanatory value is more "negative" than "positive."

I think that some historically important examples of what you search are the heuristics described by Archimedes in the Method and developed into theorems in On the Sphere and Cylinder.

Your second paragraph insinuates a dichotomy, comparing anything short of proven theorems to “reading tealeaves”.  This is rank chauvinism: outside mathematics, almost everything falls short of mathematically rigorous proof, and all good science/methodology is about developing reliable practices and intuitions for such things nonetheless.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I definitely didn't mean it that way. I did compare heuristics to reading tea leaves, but not in a negative way. I don't believe for a moment that the shape of my tea leaves can have something to do with the outcome of a football match, but I do believe that probabilistic heuristics are meaningfully connected to the truth of a mathematical statement. But with both tea leaves and heuristics, there is no clear connection between the "method of divination" and actual fact, so how can I justify this feeling that using probabilistic heuristics is not complete nonsense?

@TimothyChow If the assumption that "nothing weird happens" can be used to predict several statements that are later shown to be true, then surely one would like to be able to translate "nothing weird happens" into a precise mathematical statement. In context, this could mean proving a very powerful theorem that closely reflects the hypotheses underlying the Cramér model, so that the Riemann Hypothesis, Twin Prime Conjecture, etc. can be deduced from this theorem. In effect, this would amount to "upgrading" Cramér model itself to a theorem, or set of theorems.

@TimothyChow Cramér's expectations of which conjectures in number theory are likely to be true were not "fed into" the construction of the model, but the model nevertheless predicts the truth of various conjectures. I feel like this means it should be possible to translate the hypotheses underlying the Cramér model into a very general conjecture (or several), and this general conjecture would be a precise version of "nothing weird happens" (in the context of the distribution of primes). Has this been attempted? I have edited the main post to include this question.

@semisimpleton The Bateman-Horn conjecture is perhaps one such precise conjecture. It doesn't encompass everything about the Cramér model, though.

The Weil conjectures could qualify as a set of heuristics developed into a rigorous proof by Deligne and others:

What was really eye-catching, from the point of view of other
mathematical areas, was the proposed connection with algebraic
topology. Given that finite fields are discrete in nature, and
topology speaks only about the continuous, the detailed formulation of
Weil (a heuristic based on working out some examples) was striking and novel. It
suggested that geometry over finite fields should fit into well-known
patterns relating to Betti numbers, the Lefschetz fixed-point theorem
and so on. The analogy with topology suggested that a new homological
theory be set up applying within algebraic geometry. This took two
decades (it was a central aim of the work and school of Alexander
Grothendieck) building up on initial suggestions from Serre.


More generally, the analogy between function fields and number fields provides a heuristic: "what is true in one setting should be true in the other setting as well." However, whether we now possess an "explanation for the success" of this heuristic, as the OP requested, is maybe up for debate.

@TimothyChow I think a theory can be considered a "full explanation" of the function field analogy only if it can be used to prove the number field Riemann Hypothesis in a manner analogous to the proof of the Weil Conjectures

Unless I'm mistaken, @CarloBeenakker's answer is not about the analogy between number fields and function fields, but rather about the analogy between some algebro-geometric concepts and some topological concepts, which I think has been fully realised as a precise theory
